# Google Charts Manually add Trendline

Tags: charts, google-visualization, trendline

Google added Trendlines to Google Charts. It's nice and you just give the point coordinates and it will automatically calculate the trend line. 
It's nice but I need to add the trendline manually. Do you know if there is any possibility? 
A combination of both, scattered chart and line chart is sadly not possible I think so I have to do it with trend line.

Thank you.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify your own trendline.  If you can calculate your own, you can add it to a LineChart as an additional data series.  You can fake a ScatterChart with a LineChart by setting the `series.<series index>.pointSize` option to something larger than 0 and the `series.<series index>.lineWidth` option to 0.

```
series: {
    0: {
        // "scatter" series
        pointSize: 3,
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    1: {
        // "trendline" series
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would an end-user use this?